# NiFi `ValidateRecord` fails to validate XML records that `ConvertRecord` successfully processes using same schema

Tags: xml, validation, etl, apache-nifi, record

I already posted a jira for this though I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-11577

**Input Data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Entry xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/foo">
   <wd:Req_ID>REQ-7602</wd:Req_ID>
   <wd:Job_Requisition Descriptor="REQ-7602 Trader (Open)">
      <wd:ID type="WID">91384a20a89001a955bb7ded1401271f</wd:ID>
      <wd:ID type="Job_Requisition_ID">REQ-7602</wd:ID>
   </wd:Job_Requisition>
<wd:wd:Report_Entry>
```

**Output of Convert Record**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<PendingHiresEntryType>
  <requisition_id>REQ-7602</requisition_id>
  <job_requisition>
    <id_field>
      <content_value>91384a20a89001a955bb7ded1401271f</content_value>
      <type>WID</type>
    </id_field>
    <id_field>
      <content_value>REQ-7602</content_value>
      <type>Job_Requisition_ID</type>
    </id_field>
    <description>REQ-7602 Trader (Open)</description>
  </job_requisition>
</PendingHiresEntryType>
```

**Avro Schema Used**

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "PendingHiresEntryType",
  "namespace" : "ns",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "requisition_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "aliases" : [ "Req_ID" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "job_requisition",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "WdDescribedIdType",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "id_field",
          "type" : [ "null", {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "record",
              "name" : "WdAttributedIdType",
              "fields" : [ {
                "name" : "content_value",
                "type" : [ "null", "string" ]
              }, {
                "name" : "type",
                "type" : "string"
              } ]
            }
          } ],
          "default" : null,
          "aliases" : [ "ID" ]
        }, {
          "name" : "description",
          "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
          "default" : null,
          "aliases" : [ "Descriptor" ]
        } ]
      }
    } ],
    "default" : null,
    "aliases" : [ "Job_Requisition" ]
  } ]
}
```

I'm expecting this record to pass `ValidateRecord` but it's failing; whereas `ConvertRecord` successfully confirmed the fields and their values.

[image]

[image: settings for ValidateRecord]

[image: settings for GenerateFlowFile]